# How to log using django background tasks?

Tags: django, background-task, python-logging, django-logging

I can easily create logs throughout the application using the logging module, but inside a django background task it does not work.

```
import logging
from background_task import background

log = logging.getLogger("django")

@background(schedule=1)
def do_something():
    log.info("it worked")
```

running do_something() does not log anything, but if I remove the decorator it works...
Does anyone know how to make it work?

Answer (score 1):

Increase the schedule time and try

```
import logging
from background_task import background

log = logging.getLogger("django")

@background(schedule=10)
def do_something():
    log.info("it worked")
```